# Is this is possible to fetch data through API that how much followers a snapchat user have?

Tags: api, snapchat

Hello Stack overflow community,
I am trying to create an app where a user can put the link or username of his/her snapchat profile. And I want my app to automatically get the user's amount of followers he/she have and save it into a sheet. The reason for doing this is because then I want to assign advertising projects to him/her according to the followers he/she have. I want to fetch that data automatically through the API when a user enter his profile link or username.
And is it possible to check the amount of views a user get on any post by using link of that post through the API